# Powering NodeMCU

Tags: power-supply, nodemcu

I am trying to power a NODEMCU board using a battery. I am using a [TLV713P](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlv713p) to regulate the voltage. Can I power a nodeMCU ESP32 board using this regulated voltage by giving it to the 3V3 pin?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you please show a schematic of said board with said TLV713P in particular?

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cu75DCQVYAE1R5A.jpg ... here you go!

Comment: To have an answerable question, you need to establish a credible figure for the worst-case current consumed by the ESP32, probably when the radio is active.

Comment: The Board consumes 110mA when bluetooth is active.

Answer (score 0):

The TLV713 is a low-dropout regulator, means it's not boosting up the input voltage. So if you want to get 3.3V output you need your input to be 3.6V (assuming your NodeMCU needs 100mA).
So you'd need 3x 1.2V batteries in series or 1x 3.6V battery to reach that voltage level.

Comment: i am using a lithium ion battery with capacity of 1200 mAh.

Comment: Then that should be okay

Comment: You are both neglecting to consider the discharge curve of the batteries contemplated.  For the lithium ion types which are typically intended to supply very light loads for a long time, you should also consider how they respond to pulsed load, such as a radio transmitting at many times its quiescent power draw.  Something like a CR2032 will not be up to this task, the very largest cells in that chemistry might.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Lithium-ion intended for light loads? Are you confused with lithium primary batteries (which the CR2032 are)? Because lithium-ion batteries are capable of sourcing impressive currents and are commonly for medium-high draw loads (laptops, drones, car jump-starters).